# Do we have a stance on critique questions for whole portfolios?

Tags: discussion, critique

So I just ran into this question in which OP is asking which aspects of design his work is lacking:
[Never studied Design, but work in design, where/how can I catch up on the things I missed](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/109333/never-studied-design-but-work-in-design-where-how-can-i-catch-up-on-the-things)

My issue with this is it's very difficult to answer the question without seeing OP's work as a whole and I think there is value in answering questions like this so long as we have the proper information. Currently the question is still up with 4 close votes (2 for too broad, 2 for opinion-based). I was about to suggest to the OP to supply examples of his work for a more general critique. I think this would be completely answerable and not that subjective. I don't recall ever seeing critique questions on whole portfolios of work though. Would our standard guidelines for critique be applicable for this situation?

Comment: I think the question you linked to is asking for an *education* in design.. and can't be effectively answered by anything short of at least a 6 week course. `:)`